# How to generate an excel file using PHPExcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am trying reflect some data in a excel file using PHPExcel, when a function is called. The file is getting downloaded, but all that is displayed on the excel file are hyperlinks from the main menu, and no data from the database. The query works fine in MySql.

```
function downloadBNF() {

            global $DB;   

                    $fileName = 'barcodefound';
```

Header files

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $fileName . '.xls"');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
```

Class file

```
require_once 'protectExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';

require_once 'protectExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
```

Code for generating the excel file

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setSheet(true);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setInsertRows(true);



$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Favorite');

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A1:R1');

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1',$head);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A3','Party Code');

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B3','Party Name');

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C3','Barcode');

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D3','Date');

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E3','Serial No');

$row =4;

$fromDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_REQUEST['BNFFrom'])); 

$toDate =  date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_REQUEST['BNFTo']));
```

Sql query

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `".$DB->pre."sample_not_found` where date >='$date%' and date <='$date1%' and partyCode !='0' ";  

 $rows = $DB->dbRows($sql);
 $DB->numRows;
```

Rest of the code

```
         if($DB->numRows > 0) {
 foreach($rows as $d){
                  $pcode = $_COOKIE['PARTYCODE'];
                  $sql1 ="select * from mx_party_master where kunnr = $pcode ";
                  $res = $DB->dbRow($sql1);
                  $pname = $res['NAME1'];

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$row, $d['partyCode']);

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$row, $pname);

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$row, $d['barcode']);

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$row, $d['date']);

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$row, $srno) ;
                $row++;

}
```

Generating output

```
        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
                 $objWriter->save('php://output');

                $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
                $objWriter->save('excel-files/' . $fileName . '.xls');

        exit;   

}
}
```

Comment: you know that you are echoing the query instead of running it, do you?

Comment: Hi. Sorry, I just removed the echo from the program and it's showing the same thing.